# Search for PHP array value

Tags: php, arrays, search

```
"cuisines": [
            {
                "id": 61,
                "name": "mexican"
            },
            {
                "id": 63,
                "name": "Indian"
            },
            {
                "id": 64,
                "name": "Thai"
            }
        ],
```

I want search in array like when i search with "m" new array will be.

```
"cuisines": [
                {
                    "id": 61,
                    "name": "mexican"
                }
            ],
```

How can i do that ?

Any suggestion ?

Thanks.

Comment: Filter as this role: if the name include the char "m"?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: You've provided a JSON instead of an array. Are you sure you want to parse an array and do a regex?

Comment: <?php 
    $json = '{"cuisines": [{"id": 61, "name": "mexican"}, {"id": 63, "name": 
    "Indian"},{ "id": 64,"name":"Thai"}]}';
    function filterArray($element, $key = "i") {
        return (stripos($element['name'], $key) !== false & 1);
    }
    $array = json_decode($json, true); 
    $needle = "m"; 
    $filteredArray = array();
    $filteredArray["cuisines"] = array_filter($array["cuisines"], function($elem) 
    use($needle){
        return (stripos($elem['name'], $needle) !== false & 1);
    });    
    echo json_encode($filteredArray);
    ?>

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php):

```
$search = 'm';

$array = [
    "cuisines" => [
            [
                "id" => 61,
                "name" => "mexican"
            ],
            [
                "id" => 63,
                "name" => "Indian"
            ],
            [
                "id" => 64,
                "name" => "Thai"
            ]
        ],
];

$array['cuisines'] = array_filter($array['cuisines'], function ($item) use ($search) {
    return stripos($item['name'], $search) !== false;
});
```

Comment: How to print return value ?

Comment: what do you mean? you can loop over the `$array['cuisines']` and print the results

Answer (score 1):

array_filter can be a solution. Example:

```
<?php
$data = '{"cuisines": [
    {
        "id": 61,
        "name": "mexican"
    },
    {
        "id": 63,
        "name": "Indian"
    },
    {
        "id": 64,
        "name": "Thai"
    }
]}';

$data = json_decode($data, true);
$search = 'm';
$data = array_filter($data['cuisines'], function ($item) use ($search) {
    return !!(false !== strpos($item['name'], $search));
});

print '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```